# Fill DataGirdView from 3 tables from Sql

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I have 3 tables in sql which structure is like below:

tbl1

```
NID int, HinTitle ntext, dtposted datetime
```

tbl2

```
CID int, NID int, CCID int
```

tbl3

```
MID int, NID int, strImg Image, filename varchar
```

Now tbl1's NID is primary key and also foreign key for tbl2 and tbl3.

tbl2 can contain multiple value with tbl1's ID and same in tbl3. like below:

tbl1 sample Data::

```
 NID   HinTitle     dtposted
    1     -some text-  -date-
    2     -some text-  -date-
```

tbl2 sample Data:

```
CID   NID CCID
1      1   33
2      1   44
3      1   22
4      2   77
5      2   11
```

tbl3 sample data

```
MID  NID   strImage        filename
1     1     -Binary Data-     aa
2     1     -Binary Data-     bb
3     2     -Binary Data-     cc
```

Now what i want is when i fetch all the data from these tables then it should be like :

```
NID HinTitle      CCID CCID CCID  strImage  strImage   filename  filename
 1   -Some Text-   33   44   22   -binary-  -binary-    aa        bb
 2   -Some Text-   77   11   --   -binary-    --        cc        --
```

so that i can bind the values to a DataGridView in VB.NET

i didnt find any query that let me do this:

i have tried coalesce but it can apply only to varchar not on text and Image.

i don't know how to do that as if it is only for single values like for every id there is only one value then i can handle through join but what to do here??
n its urgent i want query asap.. as due to this my whole project is stuck...